# Counting the number of paths traversing the nodes of the intersections of a binary tree with concentric circles

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following figure that could be described as the representation of a binary tree whose branches split on 5 concentric circles. It contains 63 knots.

[image]

How many related paths are there that link the 63 nodes using 62 "segments" belonging to the tree or the circles?

An example of such path:

[image]

Comment: You could try using the Matrix Tree theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem), and get a computer to compute the determinant if you only need it for this specific graph.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could compute the solution thanks to nathey who pointed me to the Matrix Tree theorem. For those interested it's  2.019165124017958*10^28